# How to be real time with grafana?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, real-time, grafana, dashboard

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC to create a web page, which contains a dashboard created with Grafana.

```
<iframe src="URL" width="xxx" hight="xxx" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
```

Now I have a problem. It can show the dashboard, but the data presented is the data before the URL was obtained by pressing share. In other words, it can not be presented in real time.

How can I let it be real time ? Does someone have any idea?

Comment: how does the iframe code related to your question?

Comment: I use this way get the dashboard...

Comment: But I think the main problem is Grafana offer old information

Comment: it's almost 2022, don't use IFRAME anymore

Comment: What should I use to replace IFRAME?

Comment: fetch the page via JS and populate in a container like DIV

Comment: I bet you have only Grafana SNAPSHOT in the iframe, not a real dashboard. https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/sharing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the way to show the real time.
Just remove `Fromxxxtoxxx`